# how to sent a text to a specified email address when pressing a button html and javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function sendEmailToUser(){

  var msgTo = "cigma@gmail.com";
  var msgFrom = "drrama@gmail.com";
  var messageBody = " Your code is 1234567";
  var msgSubject = "CODE";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/services/Mail.asmx/SendMail",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{ 'body':'"  + messageBody + "'," +
        "'to': '" + msgTo + "'," +
        "'from': '" + msgFrom + "'," +
        "'subject': " + msgSubject + "'" +
        "}",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function (transport) { if (transport.status == 200) $("#formcontainer").html("Success"); else alert("Please try again later"); }
          });

}
```

This is my function in javascript code that is called when ever a button is clicked, so as to sent text to the specified email address as shown in the code, but the function always returns "Please try again later" as a error message. It does not sent a text to cigma@gmail.com

Comment: E-Mail is supposed to be sent from your backend server.

Comment: Did you setup `/services/Mail.asmx/SendMail` to actually send emails? What does your server log say? What is the value of `transport.status`? And your `data` does not contain JSON at all.

Comment: Also, don't create a JSON string manually, use `JSON.stringify` or your JSON will be malformed